# WorkManager existing work policy APPEND_OR_REPLACE doesn't behave as expected

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm currently using a `CoroutineWorker` from `androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.5.0`.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. Enqueue workers with `beginUniqueWork` and same `uniqueWorkName`, with policy `ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND_OR_REPLACE`.
2. This will run the workers sequentially, and if a work fails or get cancelled, the expected behavior will be, according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingWorkPolicy#APPEND_OR_REPLACE):

> If there are failed or cancelled prerequisites, these prerequisites are dropped and the newly-specified work is the start of a new sequence.

And what's happening is, all or the queued workers gets cancelled if a previous one also gets cancels (or fails). And this should be the expected behavior of `ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND` but not `ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND_OR_REPLACE`.

[image: expected behavior -> actual behavior]

Any ideas why this is happening? How to avoid queued unique workers to also get cancelled?

Comment: I am also looking for the answer to this but could not find it. Temporarily, I used return result success for Worker in any case so the chain continues. 
I suggest you also check here: https://twitter.com/danlew42/status/1214562086585421826?s=20

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately that won't work for my use case since I want to also be able to cancel the unique work. Returning always success wouldn't help in that case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71657305/847661 might help explain why it happened.

Answer (score 8):

The name of `APPEND_OR_REPLACE` is misleading, by reading this you will think that this `Worker` will REPLACE the previous worker in case of failure, or APPEND if it is RUNNING, which is wrong!

`APPEND_OR_REPLACE` means APPEND this worker to the running **chain** OR REPLACE the chain with a new one if the previous failed (create a new chain and start over, it is like a hard reset)

##### pseudo code

```
if (getChainWithUniqueTag(TAG).status == CANCELLED || FAILED) {
    createNewChine()
}
addRequestToChainWithTag(TAG,request)
```

Now It should make more sense, it is about the state of current **chain** and not the **Work**

---

To confirm this more, try to start a worker1 with a unique name, and then fail it (by calling `Result.failure`) and then create another worker2 with `APPEND` with the same unique name, `worker2` will fail directly before starting because it belongs to a failing chain.

If you try the same scenario but with `APPEND_OR_REPLACE`, `worker2` will start a new chain and continue working normally.

Consider this example :

```
val request1 = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SleepWorker>()
                .setInputData(workDataOf(KEY_BREAK_AT to 5))
                .build()

val request2 = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SleepWorker>()
                .build()
workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(
    TAG,
    ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND_OR_REPLACE,
    request1
)
// Infinite loop
while (workManager.getWorkInfoById(request1.id).get().state == WorkInfo.State.RUNNING){}

workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(
    TAG,
    ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND_OR_REPLACE,
    request2
)
```

`SleepWorker`

```
class SleepWorker(context: Context, parameters: WorkerParameters) :
        CoroutineWorker(context, parameters) {
        override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
            val breakAt = inputData.getInt(KEY_BREAK_AT,-1)
            repeat(10) {
                if(it == breakAt) return Result.failure()
                println("$it")
                delay(1000L)
            }
            return Result.success()
        }
}
```

Now in this case, `request1` will fail, and then we start `request2` and it will starts normally, because the FLAG is `APPEND_OR_REPLACE`,
If the flag is `APPEND` then `request2` will fail.

PS: try to move the second `enqueueUniqueWork` for `request2` before the infinite `while` loop, `request2` will fail too. makes sense no ?

because when we called `enqueueUniqueWork` the chain was good at that time, and for that the job has been added to that chain successfully.

Comment: Best explanation on the topic!

Comment: This explains the behaviour. But Is there an official documentation,  that explains this behaviour with the chain? This seems to be hidden and I can not find any official documentation.